# Having some trouble with regex and double brackets

Tags: python, regex, nested

I have *some* experience with regex, but I can't figure the following out. If I have a string like:

`'[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],[9,8,9]] aoeu [5,6,9] aoeu [[4,5,5]]'`

What regex pattern will extract, individually, `[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],[9,8,9]]` and `[[4,5,5]]`? (Any group within closed double brackets). Obviously, `'\[\[.*\]\]'` is too greedy a pattern...

Comment: Make it non-greedy :- `\[\[.*?\]\]`

Check:-https://regex101.com/r/qZ3fA1/2

Comment: what would be the output if the input is `'[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],3] bar [2,3]'?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you mean using the regex from "rock321987" ?

Comment: @steveb I'm asking op for further clarification..

Comment: @AvinashRaj In your question (for pattern `'[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],3] bar [2,3]'`), the regex from rock321987 `\[\[.*?\]\]` would not match anything because `]]` doesn't exist.

Comment: ya, his regex won't work for that particular example.

Comment: Let OP clarify the question, then we can decide the format

Comment: @AvinashRaj What would you hope to match in your example ?  The original post asks for what was given with `\[\[.*?\]\]`.  You are asking for a different match pattern.

Comment: @steveb I think `[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],3]` should also match logically(Its my thinking not `OP's`)

Comment: @rock321987 I tried the pattern you suggested for the OP (in python) and the original post string matches but `[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],3]` does not.  You would have to allow for `,3` to exist between `]]`.  Perhaps something like `'\[\[.*?\][\d,]*\]'`.  This might pick up other unwanted things though.

Comment: @steveb I am waiting for `OP's` update..Check :- https://regex101.com/r/qZ3fA1/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input follows exactly your pattern, then you can use this to make your `regex` `non-greedy`

```
p = re.compile(ur'\[\[.*?\]\]')
test_str = u"[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],[9,8,9]] aoeu [5,6,9] aoeu [[4,5,5]]"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

To handle cases like `[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],3]`, `[1,2,3,[3,5,3],3]` etc. use this regex

```
(\[[^\[\]]*\[.*?\][^\]\[]*\])
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3fA1/3)**

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/7kmVeo)**

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. The second cases mentioned should never show up in my case, as these represent matrices in mathematical expressions.

Comment: Damn it, too late :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I just wasn't fully clear/aware on lazy vs. greedy. I've got some reading/practicing to do.

Comment: @Jan Actually I had written the answer as soon as question appeared but was waiting for `op's` clarification..Finally I posted it as the `OP` did not clarified

Answer (score 1):

You could come up with some `\G` magic if you're able to use the (far better) [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) by *Matthew Barnett*:

```
(?:(?:\[)|(?!\A)\G)[^][]*(\[[^]]+\])
```

Broken down and with Python code, this will be:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r"""
    (?:             # non capturing group
        (?:\[)      # an open bracket
        |           # OR
        (?!\A)\G    # make sure it's not the beginning... 
                    # ...and that it is the start of the last match
    )
    [^][]*          # not a [ or ]
    (\[[^]]+\])     # capture anything between two brackets
    """, re.VERBOSE)

string = '[[1,2,3],[3,5,3],[9,8,9]] aoeu [5,6,9] aoeu [[4,5,5]]'

matches = [match.group(1) for match in rx.finditer(string)]
print matches
# ['[1,2,3]', '[3,5,3]', '[9,8,9]', '[4,5,5]']
```

See a <kbd>[demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sW7yQ9/2)</kbd>, additionally.

Comment: never used `regex` library of `python` but `+1` from my side for good explanation

Comment: @rock321987: Thanks. Consider trying it out though, it is really far (sic!) better as it offers some features `PCRE` has as well (`\G`, `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to name just a few).

Comment: Certainly, I will give it a try